# Iterating an NHibernate join

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, join, icriteria

This is the first time I've used NHibernate for a big project so bear with me.  Basically, I need to run a search based on 5 fields.

I want to display the results in a table.  Here is a test I've written that basically gets all Clients that have Intakes with a Staff named "DII".  When I run it, I get an error saying that some of the Intakes are null.

```
var name = new Name("Alice", "B." "Cooper");
var staff = "DII";
var fileNumber = 12345;

var crit = NHibernateHelper.GetCurrentSession().CreateCriteria(typeof(Client));
var result = crit.CreateAlias("Intakes", "i");            
        .Add(Restrictions.Like("Name.First", name.First + "%"));
        .Add(Restrictions.Like("Name.Middle", name.Middle + "%"));
        .Add(Restrictions.Like("Name.Last", name.Last + "%"));   
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("i.Staff", staff));            
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("i.FileNumber", fileNumber));
        .List<Client>();

foreach (var client in result)
{
    Assert.IsTrue(client.Intakes.All(i => i.Staff == "DII");
}
```

However, it does return the correct number of Clients.  My question is, how do I only iterate through the associated Intakes that would've been returned by the query generated by the above ICriteria?

I tried modifying the last line to be:

```
Assert.IsTrue(c.Intakes.Where(i => i != null).All(i => i.Staff == "DII"));
```

And it works correctly, except that the SQL generated is:

```
SELECT (Client + Intake Join) ...
SELECT FROM IntakeTable ...
SELECT FROM IntakeTable ...
SELECT FROM IntakeTable ...
(for each Intake that was returned with the join)
```

Meaning the it runs the Join, and then fetches all the Intakes again, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh, figured it out.  It was because of my mapping.  I was using:

```
<list ... />
```

...and ordering by a non-position column.  Because of that I was getting a bunch of null entries in my Intakes association.

I turned it into an ordered bag and everything worked as you'd expect.